# Invalid argument(s): Android settings must be set when targeting Android platform

Tags: android, flutter, dart, emulation

I have a flutter project which I till today only tested on an iPhone Emulator.

Now I am trying to run it on Android and facing this issue, When I am trying to update state via:

> context.read().updateUser(CurrentUser(obj.id, obj.firstName,
> obj.lastName, obj.email, obj.isConfirmed, false, []));

It is throwing:

> E/flutter ( 5677): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Android settings must be set when targeting Android platform.

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your local.properties file inside the android folder.
Try to put these lines in your file:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
flutter.compileSdkVersion=30
```

After that check your build.gradle (android/app/) file:

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Although it seems like your answer does go into the right direction, it is still not working after I changed the properties and build.gradle. The application does start normally until i try to log in and crashes on the state update. can it be a hint?

Comment: Can you send to me you log with last errors?